# Virtual Path in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, server.mappath

I am using this code for my LinkButton to download a file when you click on it.
Recently i got this problem, i need a virtual path .

I would like to redirect to `C:\inetpub\wwwroot`

```
 string filepath = Server.MapPath("...");           
 FileInfo myfile = new FileInfo(filepath);
```

So I don't know what to put in Server.MapPath() because if I put / it will go to the base of my folder documents and no In

Comment: Do you want to send a file to user, or upload a file by user?

Comment: The upload is done , here I just want to upload

Comment: Follow this link to know more about paths http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Dec/21/Making-Sense-of-ASPNET-Paths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to serve files from another part of your system then the best way to do this is to **create a virtual directory**.

In IIS right hand click on your website, click 'Add Virtual directory'. Give it a name and point it whereever you need it to be. E.g. new virtual directory called 'files' pointing at 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\files'.

Then from within your site you can reference these files by using

/files/filename.txt <- the **/files/** will link to your virtual directory.

You will then of course need to make sure you have your permissions set correctly to read these files but I will leave that up to you.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to move up from your root. The root means the root folder of the application. If you are trying so, it is a security breach.

So if you wish to go to the root of the application you can use `Server.MapPath("~");`

Answer (score 2):

You currently see a folder under your `My Documents` because you are running/debugging in your project folder, probably using the Development Server or IISExpress.

As soon as you deploy your site to a folder under `C:\Inetpub`, the `MapPath` will return that folder.

But, as a security measure, you cannot return a folder higher (in the tree) as the root folder from your application.

If you need that, you have to remove folders from the returned path yourself. You can use `System.IO.Path` for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Server.MapPath("~");
```

will give you current web application root.

Comment: It returns me C:\Users\Maxime.UICENTRIC\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ClientPortalCas\ClientPortalCas\ ..

Comment: @Emged: Because you're running it locally on VS web server. On IIS it will return web site's root, e.g. `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\site1`