# How to upload image from sub domain to main domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I tried to upload image from my sub domain to main domain, i am getting error like: Is not a valid virtual path. Why?

[image: error:is not a valid virtual path]

Comment: There is always a reason...darn computers

Comment: Server.MapPath expect you to pass-in relative path (which is something like "~/customerticket/1234.jpg"), it wont work on absolute url - check out documentation. Also note grabbing fields directly from FormCollection is bad mvc design - you should have strongly-typed model instead.

Comment: Thanx Ondrej, what is say, actually my main domain is made on asp.net  but my sub domain is made on mvc 4. so, i have to use upload url like  http://xyz/myfoldername/demo.jpg then how could i use  "~/customerticket/1234.jpg" ?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309001/virtual-path-in-asp-net

Answer (score 1):

Server.MapPath only works on the same application. If you want to upload your file elsewhere, there are at least 3 ways:

1. Put it on the directory that original domain could access and just read from there (it is easier if it is the same server);
2. Upload directly to your another application using [web services](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-any-type-of-file-through-a-C-Sharp-web-service/);
3. Upload it to another server's [FTP/sftp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268760/upload-file-to-ftp-using-c-sharp).